# Implementing data warehouse on the cloud

Tags: data-warehouse, redshift, azure-sql-data-warehouse

I need to implement a data warehouse on the cloud for a mid-sized company. The database size will be around 200 Gb.

My options are (so far):

- AWS with its database Redshift
- Azure with its database Synapse (formerly SQL Data Warehouse).
- SAP HANA, a columnar database that works on both AWS and Azure.

Does anyone have experience with these and can share? I'm more interested in performance rather than price. Am I missing other feasible options?

Comment: Why these three? What are your selection criteria? I'm sure there exists _someone_ who has experience with these; what would you ask that person?

Comment: I know these three, but I'm sure there are others. I'm mostly interested in performance.

Comment: All three have performance.

Comment: Redshift and Hana are columnar databases, Synapse apparently not (I cannot find information) wouldn't the first two have better performance?

Comment: _wouldn't the first two have better performance?_ Always? No. Sometimes? May be. There's no such thing as "better performance" in general; you can only discuss performance of a particular workload running in a particular environment, and only when you precisely define what "performance" means to you.

Comment: IIRC Azure recommended  DW for TB+

Comment: Yes, I agree with @MichaelGreen, for 200GB you could an ordinary Azure SQL Database and use columnstore indexes.  The default type of index in Azure Synapse Analytics (ASA, formerly Azure SQL Data Warehouse) is columnstore offering 5-10x compression, ie you 200GB could end up 20-40GB ie not big enough to make use of ASA's 60 distributions.

Comment: @wBob that seems to be the best option. I initially thought about Synapse because the database will be used as a data warehouse. But using the ordinary Azure SQL Database with column store indexes should work.

Comment: Shall I put that as the answer and you mark it?

Comment: Sure. Bob, write the answer.